# Prevent AI from using Venice

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I think the way Venice plays disturbs the game. Is there any way to disable that civilization, apart from choosing all AI individually?

Comment: You can always play as Venice yourself, then the AI cannot play as them! Kidding of course, but they are my favorite.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Out of the box, there is no way to blacklist certain civilisations.

Your best options are:

- Selecting the civilisations manually as you note, using the in-game Advanced Setup feature.
- Using the [Really Advanced Setup Mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=126959669), which allows you to disable civilisations one by one, as well as a number of other setup options (starting biases, units, terrains etc.)
- Manually disabling the civilisations you do not want to be selectable, in the game config files.

---

To manually disable the civilisations open the config file "Civ5Civilizations.xml" in a text editor. Find the civilisation you do not want to be selectable (Venice) and add the xml line `<AIPlayable>false</AIPlayable>`. This will disable the AI's ability to select that nation.

Of course, regular disclaimer that using mods, or manually editing game files is at your own risk.

Comment: IMO, faced with this, I'd just disable it in game configs. The game configs appear to be quite readable and simple XML. Your whole answer is great, I'm just commenting on you recommending the mod over this as I feel this is the far simpler solution. If I'm trying to do something, and the solution is "download this tool/mod..." often I just won't do it.

Comment: Modifying XML isn't *that* dangerous. If anything, I'd be more warry of a mod modifying the runtime. It can cause crashes, and while modifying the XML file can, too, the only thing you need to do to protect against corruption is just store a copy somewhere. Zipping a directory and naming the file with the date and possibly the change works well.

Comment: Based on what you guys have said, I've removed the recommendation for the mod - I think I was a bit overly cautious of somebody breaking their gamefiles and not being sure how to revert. But you're absolutely right, the mod doesn't guarantee any extra safety, and if anything obscures what has been changed.

Comment: Note: It's `Civ5Civilizations.Expansions.xml`